# opencv_ffmpeg module crash (IP Camera)

Tags: c++, opencv, error-handling, ffmpeg, runtime-error

I'm using IP webcam android app(It converts mobile camera into IP web camera).
 I'm running below code in Visual Studio 2015 with OpenCV 3.1.

```
VideoCapture cap; Mat img;
cap.open("http://192.168.0.101:8080/video?x.mjpeg");
while(waitKey(33)!=27)
{
    try{
        cap>>img;  //code crashes here
        if(img.empty())
        {
         cout<<"camera Closed"<<endl;
         break;
        }
         imshow("Video",img);
      } catch(...{}    
}
```

Getting below error.cIf the internet connection is slow or if the Wi-Fi is disconnected in my android device the program crashes 
**Error:**

> Exception thrown at 0x0BF2F6F0 (opencv_ffmpeg310.dll) in test.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

even if the code is wrapped within try catch block, it crashes!
Should I use try {} catch (...) block in source file, if yes, then where should I use this?
 I referred this [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6726) but did not find the right answer.

Comment: I can only assume cap.open() has failed. You will need to check if it's valid before reading from it.

Comment: Camera opens. We can watch video until Wi-Fi is turned off. `cap.IsOpened()` always returns true even when Wi-Fi is turned off @WLGfx